# Difference between a reversible change and a reversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, terminology, reversibility

**Question**

In thermodynamics what is the difference between a [reversible change](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=thermodynamics&as_epq=reversible+change) and a [reversible process](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=thermodynamics&as_epq=reversible+process)?

**Additional information**

I am new to the topic of thermodynamics and getting confused about the difference, if any, between a reversible change and a reversible process.  It seems to me that the difference is to do with the equilibrium of the system with the surroundings.

Comment: Perhaps you're asking about the difference between quasi-static and static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply about words. A process can *cause* a change.

For example: A (reversible) adiabatic process can cause a (reversible) temperature change.

Answer (score 2):

A process is something that goes on, has duration. A change has no necessary relation to time. It is a statement of difference between the initial and the final state of the process.